# Center bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, row, center

I am using bootstrap list-group to display links to itunes, amazon and google play. Each link is its own list-group-item. I would like for all of these items to be centered inline with one another. How do I do this?

```
<!-- Download badges -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="list-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-med-4 col-lg-2">
                <a href="http://hyperurl.co/cplq6c" class="list-group-item" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-apple fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>itunes</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-med-4 col-lg-2">
                <a href="http://hyperurl.co/1qcfl6" class="list-group-item" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-amazon fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>amazon</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-med-4 col-lg-2">
                <a href="http://hyperurl.co/mb95g4" class="list-group-item" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-google fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>google play</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To be more clear, I would like to have the list-group centered on the page.

Comment: To clarify, you want the text centered in the list-group-item or the list-group centered on the page?

Comment: list-group centered on the page please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `col-lg-offset-*` classes.  [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/fnvHJ4c0xK).  You need it on your first column.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-med-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-3">
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: That worked! I was using the offset as well, but I was applying it to all three 'list-group-items'. I understand a little better now on how it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

to

```
<div class="container">
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works? Changing fluid to fixed-width does not imply changing centering.